# Export the SELECT to a text file

Tags: sql, debugging, sql-server-2005, export

I debug a SQL Server 2005 Stored Procedure, and have a query like `SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE INNER JOIN OTHER_TABLE etc`.

How can I do to export the results of this query to a txt file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this sites below:

[Export a text file from a SQL Stored Procedure - SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383142/export-a-text-file-from-a-sql-stored-procedure)

[Simple way to export SQL Server data to Text Files - mssqltips](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1633/simple-way-to-export-sql-server-data-to-text-files/)

Best Regards

Comment: "simple way" does create a file for "SELECT * FROM sysfiles" but any output for "SELECT * FROM MYTABLE"

Comment: Write your answer here, not link to other blogs.